# Colab pro with Gsuite

Tags: google-colaboratory, google-workspace

We are using gsuite for our company

1. Is it possible to buy colab pro for specific users
2. Is it possible to buy colab pro for for all users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presently, no. It seems Colab is not included in GSuite. I'd recommend asking your GSuite billing point of contact how best to proceed if you'd like to request a group buy of Colab Pro.